# Most efficient way to get opp. products with a certain line item schedule date

Tags: visual-workflow, filters, opportunitylineitemschedule

We have a screen flow (via button) that creates sales orders based on the month and year selected by the user.  Currently, it builds the order with all products on the opportunity with a schedule record that matches that month/year combo selected.  We have been asked to allow the users to select the specific products that want to include in the order. So if there are 8 products on the opportunity and 5 of those products match the date and should be included, I want to allow users to select from those 5 which to include in the order.

My current pseudo code is this:

- Get all opportunity product records where OpportunityID = recordId >
  Opportunity ID
- Loop through the collection of product records and add each
  record ID to a text list
- Get all line item schedule records where OpportunityLineItemId "in" that text list
- Apply a collection filter to the schedules to only include the ones that match the month/year selected in the initial screen

What I want to do now is present a screen to the user with only the product records that match the list of filtered schedules and let them select which products to use.  My first thought was to loop back through the filtered schedule records and just get each product record in a collection.  But that seems very inefficient.  Is there a better way to do this?

Hopefully this made sense.  TIA for any help.

Comment: Sounds like a job for screen flow rather than record-triggered: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/screen-flows/get-started-with-screen-flows

Comment: Thanks @identigral.  I realize now that I misspoke.  It actually is a screen flow.  The user clicks a button and they get a screen asking them to choose the date and then the order is created.  It incorrectly said record-triggered flow.

Comment: If it's 5-8 products, it doesn't matter how you filter the collection - via some upfront query or looping through it or by using a [collection filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_filter_collection.htm&release=236&type=5) or...